# How to handled the huge records in Jquery data table

Tags: jquery, datatables

I need to handle the huge data records in jquery data table, But In my case if the records are more than 2000 , data table warning alert I am getting, it is not loading the data.

Here is my code :

```
var $table=$('#MCNRes').dataTable( {
    "bFilter": false,
    "bDestroy": true,
    "bJQueryUI": true,
    "bServerSide": true,
    "sDom": '<"H"l<"toolbar">Tfr>t<"F"ip>',
    "ajax": {
     url: 'getResult.php',
     type: 'POST'
    }
});
```

Here is div  I am displaying the data

```
<div id=McnAddResult> </div>
```

Here serverside data response :

```
 $result = $afscpMcnMod->getMcnDetails($mcn_no, $mcn_sf, $cust_nm,    $emp_id, $anc);
$newarray = array(
        "draw"            => $_POST['draw'],
        "recordsTotal"    => sizeof($result),
        "recordsFiltered" => sizeof($result),
        "data"            => $result
    );
echo json_encode($newarray);
```

Comment: You should look in to using the paging features of DataTables.

Comment: Pagination is there in this case. "sDom": '<"H"l<"toolbar">Tfr>t<"F"ip>',

Comment: The `sDom` property only governs where the paging controls are displayed. It has nothing to do with the implementation of paging at all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to decide which processing mode you want to use: client-side or server-side.

You're currently using server-side processing mode with `bServerSide: true` however seems like you're returning full data set. In this mode data *only for requested page* should be returned instead. Also it doesn't seem that you're handling filtering and sorting.

jQuery DataTables distribution includes [`ssp.class.php`](https://github.com/DataTables/DataTables/blob/master/examples/server_side/scripts/ssp.class.php) that helps develop server-side processing scripts, see [sample code](https://github.com/DataTables/DataTables/blob/master/examples/server_side/scripts/server_processing.php).

If you have under 10,000 records, you may want to use client-side processing mode instead by removing `bServerSide: true` and using `deferRender: true` as suggested by another answer. However with this mode your code needs to be changed to:

```
$newarray = array(
   "data" => $result
);
```

Comment: Yes, Records size will be increasing more than 10,000 also , so I need to  use server side processing...

Comment: @chaya, then use `ssp.class.php` for correct processing of server-side requests. The response you're generating is not 100% accurate.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `deferRender` option :

https://datatables.net/examples/ajax/defer_render.html

https://datatables.net/reference/option/deferRender

"...if you load a data set with 10,000 rows, but a paging display length of only 10 records, rather than create all 10,000 rows, when deferred rendering is enabled, DataTables will create only 10. When the end user then sorts, pages or filters the data the rows needed for the next display will be created automatically. This effectively spreads the load of creating the rows across the life time of the page."

Comment: I have tried with "deferRender": true  option , but still I am getting the error

Comment: Ok, so your problem is not related to number of rows (2000 isn't a big number). Look in your browser console : do you have any error message ? And in your php error.log ?

Comment: Yes, Record size  will be increasing  more than 10,000  also, It will break the datatable from loading the data